# Does 'config(bg=[color])' not work in classes?

Tags: python, tkinter

I used a class with `tkinter` to make a window. However, changing the background color does not work for me. I have looked at the other question and tried every solution to changing the background color, but none work. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
        self.mazeDrawing()


    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('Maze')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.master.geometry("900x600")
        self.master.config(bg='black')

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.clientExit)

        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)


    def clientExit(self):
        exit()


    def mazeDrawing(self):
        canvas = Canvas(self.master, width='900', height='600')
        canvas.pack()
        canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 800, 500, outline='red')


root = Tk()
App = Window(root)
App.mainloop()
```

As you can see, I clearly defined the background color as black in `init_window` as `self.master.config(bg='black')`, but when I run the code, I get a white window. I'm not sure if this is simply because my computer sucks or if I am violating some python rule. Please plug this into your editor and run the code.

Comment: No, it really is black. But you fill the entire area with your frame. If you reduce the frame and canvas you should see the black background.

Comment: Is there a way to change the canvas's color? Like make it's background black

Comment: if i surround the entire thing in a rectangle and color it black, the canvas still has a white border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background of your window is indeed black. However, you're covering it with a canvas so you won't be able to see the black. You can see this by adding the options `padx=10` and `pady=10` when packing the canvas to see the black that surrounds the canvas. If you want the canvas to be black, set it's background color to be black (eg: `canvas = Canvas(self.master, ..., background='black'`)

In the comments it sounds like you are complaining about the thin white border around the canvas. If you don't want that border, set `borderwidth` to zero, and also set `highlightthickness` to zero.